# TeamCity does not see changes in Git branch

Tags: git, teamcity-9.0

I have two git branches set up, dev and test.  The dev branch is frequently committed to, then periodically merged into test.  I have a teamcity project set up with the VCS root pointed to dev as the default branch, and test included in the branch specification of the VCS root (`+:refs/heads/test`).  Teamcity picks up changes to the dev branch just fine, but when merging to test, it doesn't detect when the merge is committed and sync'ed.  How can I get TeamCity to recognize the push to test and deploy appropriately?

Comment: Since you mention it "picks up changes to the dev branch" I assume you have a VCS trigger setup. Would you happen to have a branch filter on that trigger?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need this test branch? What purposes does it serve?

If you need it only for deploying to TEST environment maybe tagging a DEV branch is enough? So instead of merging code to TEST branch (and having TC build fired automatically by this merge) how about just running a build configuration (when you think code is ready for TEST) that will tag a code (with e.g. version and date) and performs tests, does a deploy or whatever is necessary?

I have multiple DEV builds a day but for QA env we have a weekly builds set up, but it does not require separate branch for code.